# Collatz sequence. Dealing with exception handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I just started learning python 3 and have been having some issues when trying to understand exception handling. I am going through a tutorial book that has given me a small project called the 'The Collatz Sequence'

its essentially a program that evaluates any integer down to '1' by using a some simple math.

I have been able to successfully get the program to work UNTIL the user inputs anything but an integer. At first I was getting ValueError, which was corrected by using the *except ValueError:*.

Now I seem to be getting *NameError: name 'number' is not defined*

Any help is appreciated. Just trying to get an understanding of exception handling.

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        even_number = number//2
        print(even_number)
        return even_number
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        odd_number = (number * 3 + 1)
        print(odd_number)
        return odd_number

try:
    number = int(input('Enter Number: '))
except ValueError:
    print('Please enter an integer')
while int(number) != 1:
    number = collatz(number)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility would be to keep track of whether an integer was given as input using a boolean value. Consider the (adapted) code below:

```py
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        even_number = number//2
        print(even_number)
        return even_number
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        odd_number = (number * 3 + 1)
        print(odd_number)
        return odd_number

# Keep asking for input until the user inputs an integer
got_integer = False
while not got_integer:
    try:
        number = int(input('Enter Number: '))
        got_integer = True
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter an integer')

while int(number) != 1:
    number = collatz(number)
```

As you can see, I define a boolean variable `got_integer`. Initially, I set its value to `False`. After this variable definition is a while loop, which keeps executing the loop body until the value of `got_integer` is `True`. Now you simply set the value of `got_integer` to `True` upon a succesfull input (*i.e.* if the execution of the line `number = int(input('Enter Number: '))` succeeds).

Comment: I just want to make sure that I I understand it correctly. The "while not got_integer" evaluates as True. Because of this the program is able to run the try clause. When an integer is entered, the got_integer inside the try block then evaluates to True. This then changes the "while not got_integer" to technically false. Then the program can move to "while int(number) !=1:"    is this right? just want to make sure i get it.

Comment: @Mtcvoid Exactly. I think the major benefit of this approach is that you only catch errors related to input. If you'd put all your code in the try-block, it would catch _any_ ValueError generated in the block, not only the ValueError related to the input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the logic inside try block if you are getting exceptions.
Then you can handle it when you face with an exception. In your case you can have the while block inside the try like below. According to the exceptions you can handle them below as you have done already.

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        even_number = number//2
        print(even_number)
        return even_number
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        odd_number = (number * 3 + 1)
        print(odd_number)
        return odd_number

try:
    number = int(input('Enter Number: '))
    if number != 1:
        number = collatz(number)
except ValueError:
    print('Please enter an integer')
```

Comment: This makes sense. I initially had my original code set up the exact same way but I was getting syntax errors on the while number =! :  .......I forgot the indentation to make it apart of the block. Thank you!

Comment: In case you need to ask input until you need an integer  input you can use a flag but either case its better to handle exception.